# What does [rospack] Permission denied means?

Tags: ros, permission, ros-kinetic, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've just installed ROS Kinetic with other packages as opencv, gazebo, turtlebot, rplidar and intelrealsense. The thing is that now when I open a new terminal console window or tab appear three errors about rospack, the following:

```
[rospack] Unable to create temporary cache file /home/pc2/.ros/.rospack_cache.38dCXr: Permission denied
[rospack] Unable to create temporary cache file /home/pc2/.ros/.rospack_cache.t3sveu: Permission denied
[rospack] Unable to create temporary cache file /home/pc2/.ros/.rospack_cache.hlp6zx: Permission denied
```

And I can't do anything, neither run roscore.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311676/what-does-%5Brospack%5D-permission-denied-means?/) by [magole](https://answers.ros.org/users/38862/magole/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-12-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-29**:
Did you at any point run `rospack` as the `root` user? What is the output of:

```
ls -al /home/pc2/.ros/.rospack_cache.38dCXr
```

Is `pc2` the name of your user account, or some other user?

**Comment by [magole](https://answers.ros.org/users/38862/magole/) on 2018-12-29**:
pc2 is the only user in the computer. I didn't run rospack at any moment, I just installed all and this appeared. I've seen that each time I open a new terminal different files cause this rospack error. The output is always:
ls: can't access to 'the file': file or directory doesen't exist

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-30**:
What is the output of `ls -al $HOME/.ros`?

**Comment by [magole](https://answers.ros.org/users/38862/magole/) on 2018-12-30**:
thanks for the feedback gvdhoorn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I got it, I changed the permissions on the `~/.ros` archive and that's it

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.ros
```

---

Originally posted by [magole](https://answers.ros.org/users/38862/magole/) with karma: 16 on 2018-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-30**:
Which user was the owner before you changed it to your user?

**Comment by [magole](https://answers.ros.org/users/38862/magole/) on 2019-01-04**:
root I think so, but Im not sure. I just changed the user, someone told me to do it in order to solve the problem so I did it without knowing which user was owning the archive ./ros before.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:\

> root I think

well that would certainly be the problem there.